# Unable to join server that is hosted in same apartment building same ISP

Tags: networking

Okay so, here is the problem (and this seems to be the problem for both of us if we are trying to access something that the other has hosted): I have a global IP of 99.99.99.127 (Not my real global IP, but you get the gist), three floors down in the same apartment building and with the same ISP he has a global IP of 99.99.99.128. It's my strong suspicion that this is the culprit of all our woes, but I can't seem to find a solution. I've set my minecraft server up with all the necessary port forwarding and I am able to access it from in game. In addition to that, another friend of ours can access it all the way from NM (completely different ISP and global IP). When same apartment friend tries to access it just says server unreachable. I did CS in college, but I was no networking wonder, and I was hoping someone smarter than I could solve this, as I said before it's not limited to minecraft. It plagues things like Plex, Transmission, and really any server either of us host. Any help would be much appreciated!

Okay so I'm updating this as I have not found any solution thus far. Something I found that was interesting was that if I ran "tracert" from my computer to my friend's public IP I got this (it's the same if my friend runs the same command to me):

https://gyazo.com/06e9562016a88555e96b739d5fb1d8c2

Whereas, if I have a friend from another ISP run the same command it looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/0cfada566ff6c27f5ab6c1b0b5327c8f

I spoke with my ISP about this, and they said they couldn't do anything about it, so I don't know if this is on my end or what. It's incredibly frustrating as I now just discovered that on Ubisoft games (For Honor, Rainbow Six Siege) I can't join their party and they can't join me. I can join anyone else and anyone else can join me, so I'm fairly certain the two are related. Again, any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your ISP is using "carrier-grade" NAT without hairpin support.  That means the server actually has 3 IP addresses, the private one, the ISP network one (shared with all computers in the same apartment), and the public one.

You'll need to discover the ISP-network address, possibly by viewing the status page of your modem (the one which provides internet access and routing for the server) and checking the WAN-side address.  Then ask your friend to use that address when connecting.

Site such as whatismyip.org will not help with this, as they can only see the public (Internet-visible) address.

Comment: Unlikely that the OP is behind CGN if a friend from another state can access his server.

Comment: @user4556274: If it is really NAT, and not PAT-commonly-mistakenly-called-NAT, then connections from outside wouldn't have any problem.  Or, the "set up port forwarding" is done via an interface to a database honored by the CGN routers.

Comment: FYI, I did look through my entire modem page and was able to find a WAN Address. Unfortunately it was the same as what's listed as my public IP